# Association all model in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Iam new to ruby on rails, i going to create online rent system.

This is location base model

```
app/models/state.rb
Class State < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :provinces
end

app/models/province.rb
Class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :state
has_many :districts
end

app/models/district.rb
Class District < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :province
has_many :cities
end

app/models/city.rb
Class City < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :district
end
```

**First question is how can display all like below**

- Alaska
- California

  - Los Angeles
  - Fresno

    - Cincotta (Fresno)
    - Hammond (Fresno)
    - Melvin (Fresno)

      - Melvin 1
      - Melvin 2
- Arizona
- Colorado

**Second Question Is, how create breadcrumb all model**

California >> Fresno >> Melvin >> Melvin 1

Comment: i am try association all model.Added foreign key to related table table, My home.html.erb how to display tree view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to introduce a hierarchy into your data objects.
This can be done in a couple of ways. Have a look at [the ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

If you want to hard code stuff:

```
# locations_controller.rb
def index
  @locations = State.all
end

# app/views/locations/index.html.erb
<ul>
  <%= render @locations %>
</ul>

# app/views/locations/_state.html.erb
<li>
  <%= state.name %>
  <% if state.provinces.present? %>
    <ul>
      <%= render state.provinces %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</li>

# app/views/locations/_province.html.erb
<li>
  <%= province.name %>
  <% if province.districts.present? %>
    <ul>
      <%= render province.districts %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</li>

# app/views/locations/_district.html.erb
<li>
  <%= district.name %>
  <% if district.cities.present? %>
    <ul>
      <%= render district.cities %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</li>   

# app/views/locations/_city.html.erb
<li>
  <%= city.name %>
</li>
```

For Breadcrumbs you would need to introduce a ancestry method into each model. e.g.

```
class City
  ...
  def ancestry
    district.ancestry << self
  end
  ...
end

# ... other classes

class State
  ...
  def ancestry
    [self]
  end
end
```

Then you can render a breadcrumbs partial

```
# app/views/layout.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'shared/breadcrumbs', locals: { ancestry: @some_instance.
def breadcrumbs(ancestry)
  ancestry
end

# app/views/shared/_breadcrumbs.html.erb
<ul>
  <% ancestry.each do |location| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to location.name, url_for(location) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, i added ancestry gem to my application.

Comment: added new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787750/creating-has-many-association-with-ancestry-gem Please make me help