# Creating has_many association with ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ancestry

I installed ancestry gem & create Location Structure.

- Alaska
- California

  - Los Angeles
  - Fresno
  - Cincotta (Fresno)
  - Hammond (Fresno)

    - Melvin (Fresno)

      - Melvin 1
      - Melvin 2
      - Melvin 3
- Arizona
- Colorado

My post and location model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Tree
 has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

When i am add new post, how to display only depth 4 level ( **Melvin 1,Melvin 2,Melvin 3**) as drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable [cache depth](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#options-for-has_ancestry) so you can use [at_depth](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#selecting-nodes-by-depth):

```
Location.all.at_depth(4)
```

Thiscan be used to render a `select` input element:

```
<%= select :location_id, Location.all.at_depth(4) { |l| [ l.name, l.id ] } %>
```

Comment: what i am adding in post controller.. what i am add   # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

Comment: Thank you @zwippie. I create new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801193/post-and-location-association-with-ancestry-gem