# Post and Location Association with ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ancestry

My Rails application have two model. Location and Post, Location have many post.I am Using 
ancestry gem.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :location, :counter_cache => true
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Tree
 has_ancestry :cache_depth => true
 has_many :posts
end
```

**My Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@posts = Post.all
end

def show
end

def new
 @post = Post.new
end


 def edit
 end

def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
@post.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_post
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name)
 end
end
```

**If i am create new Post with which Location belongs in _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:   </h2>

  <ul>
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<%= select :location_id, Location.all.at_depth(4) { |l| [ l.name, l.id ] } %> 

<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

**Browser show error message which is display bellow**

```
ArgumentError in Posts#new
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: this error in **Posts#new** <%= select :location_id, Location.all.at_depth(4) { |l| [ l.name, l.id ] } %>

Comment: It's any problem in **Post Controller**? i am want add any code in _def new_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this fixes your error, but:

To make the dropdown working, change the `select` line to:

```
<%= f.select :location_id, Location.all.at_depth(4) { |l| [ l.name, l.id ] } %>
```

This is because you want the formbuilder `f` to handle the creation of the form element.

You also have to whitelist the `:location_id` parameter in the controller:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :location_id)
end
```

Comment: my post indexhtm.erb how to display post location? **><%= post.location.name %>** not working only working is **<%= post.category_id %>** how display post location name?

Comment: post show.html.erb `<%= @post.location.name%>`error **NoMethodError in Posts#show**

Comment: `<%= f.select :location_id, Location.all.at_depth(4) { |l| [ l.name, l.id ] } %>` how display location.name

Comment: Can any one help this question?

Comment: @MarySmith Please create a new question if it is not related to the current question.

Comment: i added question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822886/association-between-post-and-location, Thank your most help