# Association between Post and Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ancestry

This my first ruby on rails application.

Model Location and Post, Location has many post.I create location as tree structure with [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :location, :counter_cache => true
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Tree
 has_ancestry :cache_depth => true
 has_many :posts
end
```

This my Post Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @posts = Post.all
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
  @post = Post.new
 end


 def edit
 end

 def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

   respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
     format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
    else
     format.html { render action: 'new' }
     format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
   format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
   format.json { head :no_content }
  else
   format.html { render action: 'edit' }
   format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def destroy
 @post.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
   format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end

private
 def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :location_id)
 end
end
```

Creating Post with location in Post _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:   </h2>
   <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= f.input :name %>

<%= f.select :location_id, Location.all.at_depth(4) { |l| [ l.name, l.id ] } %>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**My question are**

**First question-   f.select :location_id , how display location name, not location id, i am using with simple form**

**Second question-  Post index got error in** <%= post.location.name %>

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= post.name %></td>
  <td><%= post.location.name  %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

Check the `simple_form` syntax for a dropdown. It is mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections) and you should be able to get this working by yourself.

Second question:

Does the offending `post` really have a related `location`? If it does not have one, it can not display the name of course. To counter these `nil` errors, use `try`:

```
<%= post.location.try(:name)  %>
```

`try` will call the method `name` on `location` only if `location` is not `nil`.

Comment: yes, amazing today i going to big sleep today...thnak @zwippie :)

Comment: ,created new question in ancestry,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855785/dynamic-select-with-ancestry

Answer (score 0):

**For your first question :**

Maybe you should read about "options_for_select"

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects

```
<% cities_array = City.all.map { |city| [city.name, city.id] } %>
<%= options_for_select(cities_array) %>
```

**For your second question:**
What is your error ?

Maybe one of your "post.location" is nil.
If so, try:

```
post.location.name unless post.location.nil?
```

Hope this can help