# Dynamic Select with ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ancestry

My application using ancestry gem.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_ancestry :cache_depth => true
 has_many :posts
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :location
end
```

I created some random Location,

- Alaska
- California

  - Los Angeles
  - Fresno

    - Cincotta (Fresno)
    - Hammond (Fresno)
    - Melvin (Fresno)

**My question** if user sign up form if User select California, display child Los Angles and Fresno, after select Fresno then display it's child.

I got javascript tutorial for Dropdown list http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/dropdown-list-demo.php

How is possible work with [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nested**

Firstly, if you wanted to keep them all in a single `dropdown`, we created the following helper which achieves it for you:

[image]

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def nested_dropdown(items)
    result = []
    items.map do |item, sub_items|
        result << [('- ' * item.depth) + item.name, item.id]
        result += nested_dropdown(sub_items) unless sub_items.blank?
    end
    result
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
<%= f.select(:category_ids, nested_dropdown(Category.all.arrange), prompt: "Category", selected: @category ) %>
```

This will give you the ability to call a *single* dropdown, which has been nested according to your ancestry associations

--

**Ajax**

If you want to have double dropdown boxes, you'll probably have to implement an `ajax` function to pull the required data each time the initial dropdown changes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
    get :select_item
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#first_dropdown").on("change", function(){
   $.ajax({
       url: "categories/"+ $(this).val() + "/select_item",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
          //populate second dropdown
       }
   })
});

#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
Class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json, only: :select_item

    def select_item
       category = @category.find params[:category_id]
       respond_with category.children
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank @RichPeck, i want as two selection field.. this is example http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/dropdown-list-demo.php

Comment: i create list item with, https://github.com/doabit/ancestry_selectbox_demo, but can't find http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/dropdown-list-demo.php

Comment: Let's have a look - sorry about the late reply!

Comment: i was try to do like this but it's not working, <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all.at_depth(1), :id, :name) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all.at_depth(2), :id, :name) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all.at_depth(3), :id, :name) %>

Comment: I followed @RichardPeck solution which works fine, but edit or new is not saving to database, or may be I am missing something in the strong parameters. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question, but try to follow this tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

I watched it once when needed to work with ancestry gem.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Yes i learn from Railscasts, how install ancestry gem.On that tutorial I can't find Solution.